# Where does the funding for Mathematics - Stack Exchange come from?

Tags: discussion

I encounter no ads that I am aware of, and it must cost money, which makes me wonder.

Comment: That's strange; I get *sometimes* ads of mathematica, sage and others below or above the "community bulletin". Surprisingly it is sporadic; but even more surprisingly it occurs although I have adblock+ active and the *ads* pages at stackexchange are blocked. (This is really harassing me, btw, they must have a special fancy js-function to neutralize adblock)

Comment: actually, they come initially from i.imgurl.com, and when you move the mouse over them, they "change their adress" (???) to some "meta.math.ads.*", and if you reload the page, adblock+ seems to be able to block them then. It is really distracting the concentration from the reading of the math-contents of the questions...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Those are the [Community Promotion ads](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3278/community-promotion-ads-2012) that are chosen and created by the community itself. Additionally there are in-house ads for other sites in the network.

Comment: You might be interested in [searching](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/?s=funding) some old blog posts like [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/announcing-our-series-a/), [that](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/stack-overflow-funding-chat-qa-transcript/) or [another](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/). To quote: "In 2010, we incorporated as Stack Overflow Internet Services with venture capital funding"

Comment: (Repeating my [comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4979/what/4980#comment20109_4980) on [What will happen if MSE or SE in general be closed someday?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4979/163))

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Stack Exchange is earning money by ads on the three largest sites (Stackoverflow, Superuser and Serverfault) as well as their [Careers platform](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/).

None of the SE 2.0 sites like Math earn any money at the moment.

Comment: I was also ever so slightly curious if it was part of a behavioral rewards experiment :-).

Comment: @copper.hat What, like [this](https://xkcd.com/810/)? :-D

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: Nice!

Comment: Actually no. All the money is coming from my wallet.

Answer (score 0):

please ignore this answer [see the comments below]

I have seen ads here and actually of products that I found useful, unlike the rest of the web.

Comment: [But those are Community Promotion ads](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6584/where-does-the-funding-for-mathematics-stack-exchange-come-from#comment23465_6584).

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills : so community ads are free?

Comment: Those are ads proposed by users of this site, and approved (via votes) by other users. No money changes hands. You can [propose an ad here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11920/community-promotion-ads-2014).

Comment: Although there are adds on *some sites* in the Stack Exchange network. Some information can be found here: [We're enabling display ads on select Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287242).